# Unit testing collection contents meet certain criteria using lambdas/LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, mstest

I'm using the built-in C# unit-testing classes like `Assert` and `CollectionAssert`. I want to test that all objects returned by a method call have a certain value on a given property.

Are there special classes provided for unit testing this kind of thing, or would I just use the normal collection methods and feed the results into a regular `Assert` call?

e.g. does something like this exist: `Assert.TrueForAll(myList,x => x.Prop == 123)`

Comment: I believe Fluent Assertions has something like that. But otherwise yes you would use `Assert.IsTrue(myList.All(x => x.Prop == 123))`

Comment: This seems quite reasonable as the basis of an answer

Answer (score 1):

How about returning the check?

```
mylist.ForEach(x => Assert.IsTrue(x.Prop == 123));
```

Comment: this would report a failure for every object failing though, which could be a lot - I think that's conceptually different from one test "are all objects correct"?

Comment: Hum. Wouldn't it rather break on the first failure?

Comment: I guess that's worth a try ;) You're right though, I've taken the negative approach. It is not as fun to read, but I think it would have exacly the same effect.